# AirFlow error while installing it on CentOS7

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I am trying to install Apache AirFlow on my local machine CentOS7.
I have python 2.7.
I am getting below error while installing AirFlow

```
[dsawale@localhost ~]$ pip install apache-airflow==1.10.9
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting apache-airflow==1.10.9
  Using cached apache_airflow-1.10.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.6 MB)
Collecting flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.2; python_version < "3.6"
  Downloading Flask-AppBuilder-1.13.1.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 742 kB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D2TCrh/flask-appbuilder/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-D2TCrh/flask-appbuilder/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-pNlWPA
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-D2TCrh/flask-appbuilder/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error in Flask-AppBuilder setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Could you please help me to resole this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this before installing airflow pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon Thanks! Airflow installed successfully after trying above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade setuptools using below.

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Please let me know.